# Python3 sleep() problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, sleep, flush

I was writing a simple program on Python 3.1 and I stumbled upon this:

If I run this on the IDLE it works as intended - prints `"Initializing."` and then adds two dots, one after each second, and waits for input.

```
from time import sleep

def initialize():
    print('Initializing.', end='')
    sleep(1)
    print(" .", end='')
    sleep(1)
    print(" .", end='')
    input()

initialize()
```

The problem is that when I double-click the .py to execute the file, it runs on python.exe instead of pythonw.exe, and strange things happen: it joins all the `sleep()` times i.e. makes me wait for 2 seconds, and then prints the whole string `Initializing. . .` at once. Why does this happen? Is there a way to avoid that happening in the terminal? It works fine if I use the IDLE in both windows and linux.

Comment: I imagine the reason it's buffering is because you haven't given it a `\n` yet.  In general the use of `end` will indicate you're going on and writing something immediately.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is because the output is being buffered.

You should add a `sys.stdout.flush()` after each write

Comment: And, after 4 years, I just noticed I never actually set this as an accepted answer.

Comment: Using Python 3's `print` function, you can also use the `flush` parameter, e.g. `print(" .", end='', flush=True)`

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like the difference is that stdout is automatically being flushed in IDLE. For efficiency, programming languages often save up a bunch of print calls before writing to the screen, which is a slow process.

Here's another question that has the answer you need:
[How to flush output of Python print?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-python-print)