# time.sleep in python exceution order

Tags: python, sleep

```
print(7)
sleep(10)
print(8)
```

when i typed this in Spyder's command line, I expected 7 to be printed, then after 10 seconds 8, would be printed, however, what happened was that both 7 and 8 are printed after a 10 second pause, why is this the case?

The reason I need this function is that I want Python to keep on searching for a file in a directory until it eventually appears.

```
done = os.path.exists ("done.txt")
while not done:
    sleep(10)
    done = os.path.exists ("done.txt")
```

will this work?

EDIT: corrected exist as exists.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python3 sleep() problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456581/python3-sleep-problem)

Comment: For your problem wouldn't `done` be initialized once in the beginning? `sleep(10)` will never occur then. Maybe you should check for `os.path.exist()` as the `while` condition. Like `while os.path.exists('/your/path/file.txt')`?

Comment: It should be `os.path.exists` not `os.path.exist`. Other than that, this should work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: It should be `os.path.exists` not `os.path.exist`.

Other than that, this should work fine.

Second: I think kiran.konduru misunderstood the question, but you could certainly simplify this and remove the need for the `done` variable:

```
while not os.path.exists("done.txt"):
    sleep(10)
```

Finally: The `time.sleep()` function is getting buffered in the Spyder command line, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456581/python3-sleep-problem). If you use `sys.stdout.write()` and `sys.stdout.flush()` rather than a simple `print`, things will work fine in that command line as well.